# Solve maximization problem of quadratic equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, quadratic

How do I solve a quadratic Maximization problem in MATLAB? It seems MATLAB only supports minimization problems, so is there a mathematical concept I can use?

Answer (score 10):

simply multiply by (-1) before and after using the minimization function

Comment: +1 - Correct.  Multiplying the objective function by a negative, solving the problem, then multiplying the output objective value by a negative to cancel the negative out will allow for maximizing the objective function in a minimization framework.

Comment: got you a bronze badge ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`quadprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html) function in MATLAB.

This function solves [Quadratic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) problems in MATLAB.

Of course if you want the maxima instead of the minima, you can multiply the cost function by -1.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer @Drazick seems not right.

quadprog() in matlab requires **H** to be positive definite. If we simply multiply (-1), -**H** is a negative definite matrix, which violates the requirement.

Another optimization function called fmincon( ) may help.